# Could to cast value of type '__NSArray0' to 'CIRectangleFeature'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I have been using some code in Objective C that performs `CIDetector`on a `CIImage` that is captured in `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. My goal is to get it translated over to swift 3. I have it all translated over to swift 3 but I am getting this could not cast error in my `CIRectangleFeature` methods. So I am here for help as I've been working on this for days and can't get it right. I'm sure it's something simple that I am overlooking.

This is the code in Objective C

```
- (CIRectangleFeature *)_biggestRectangleInRectangles:(NSArray     *)rectangles
{
if (!rectangles.count) return nil;

float halfPerimiterValue = 0;

CIRectangleFeature *biggestRectangle = rectangles.firstObject;

for (CIRectangleFeature *rect in rectangles)
{
    CGPoint p1 = rect.topLeft;
    CGPoint p2 = rect.topRight;
    CGFloat width = hypotf(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y);

    CGPoint p3 = rect.topLeft;
    CGPoint p4 = rect.bottomLeft;
    CGFloat height = hypotf(p3.x - p4.x, p3.y - p4.y);

    CGFloat currentHalfPerimiterValue = height + width;

    if (halfPerimiterValue < currentHalfPerimiterValue)
    {
        halfPerimiterValue = currentHalfPerimiterValue;
        biggestRectangle = rect;
    }
}

return biggestRectangle;
```

}

This function is being called from another function and here it is in Objective C

```
- (CIRectangleFeature *)biggestRectangleInRectangles:(NSArray *)rectangles
{
    CIRectangleFeature *rectangleFeature = [self _biggestRectangleInRectangles:rectangles];
```

Now this function is being called from within `-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` if an `if` returns `true` like so

```
if (self.isBorderDetectionEnabled)
{
    if (_borderDetectFrame)
    {
        _borderDetectLastRectangleFeature = [self biggestRectangleInRectangles:[[self highAccuracyRectangleDetector] featuresInImage:image]];
        _borderDetectFrame = NO;
    }
```

It is also being called in another method that captures the images and saves them in basically the same manner

Now I have it translated to swift 3 like this

```
func bigRectangle(rectangles: [Any]) -> CIRectangleFeature {


    var halfPerimiterValue: Float = 0
    var biggestRectangles: CIRectangleFeature? = rectangles.first as! CIRectangleFeature? // This is the line causing the casting error
    for rect: CIRectangleFeature in rectangles as! [CIRectangleFeature]{
        let p1: CGPoint = rect.topLeft
        let p2: CGPoint = rect.topRight
        let width: CGFloat = CGFloat(hypotf(Float(p1.x) - Float(p2.x), Float(p1.y) - Float(p2.y)))
        let p3: CGPoint = rect.topLeft
        let p4: CGPoint = rect.bottomLeft
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(hypotf(Float(p3.x) - Float(p4.x), Float(p3.y) - Float(p4.y)))
        let currentHalfPerimiterValue: CGFloat = height + width
        if halfPerimiterValue < Float(currentHalfPerimiterValue) {
            halfPerimiterValue = Float(currentHalfPerimiterValue)
            biggestRectangles = rect
        }
    }
    return biggestRectangles!
}
```

I am calling it in swift 3 basically the same as the Objective C manner like this

```
func biggestRectangle(rectangles: [Any]) -> CIRectangleFeature {
    let rectangleFeature: CIRectangleFeature? = self.bigRectangle(rectangles: rectangles)
```

That function is being called the same way as in Objective C like this.

```
if self.isEnableBorderDetection == true{
        if self.borderDetectFrames == true {
            self.borderDetectLastRectangleFeature = self.biggestRectangle(rectangles: [self.highAccuracyRectangleDetector().features(in: image)])
            self.borderDetectFrames = false
        }
```

From within the function `func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {}`

Now I have tried changing the array type from `[Any]` to `[CIRectangleFeature]` in both functions but then I have problems with `CIFeature` being an unrelated type.

Hopefully some one can have a look at this and point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: U can't cast mother object to inherited (and so often, extended), it's immorally.

Comment: so should i change the `[Any]` to `[CIFeature]` instead of `[CIRectangleFeature]` like I tried

Comment: I'm think u must be sure what is in `[[self highAccuracyRectangleDetector] featuresInImage:image]` return in debug first.

Comment: Can u share simple project with issue? I need debug this for help.

Comment: that is this function `func highAccuracyRectangleDetector() -> CIDetector {
        let options: [String: Any] = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAspectRatio: 1.0]
        return CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: options)!
    }` the `featuresInImage:image` is a function within the CoreImage framework of the type `CIFeature`

Comment: @Bimawa how might i share it with you? I don't have gitHub account

Comment: dropbox or anything

Comment: How work with casting: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html 
I think we must be use downcasting in your case. Be cause we not sure what is hold NSArray.

Comment: ok let me a moment i debug this

Comment: @Bimawa sure but in the NSArray is the `CIFeature` that is returned by the features function from within the CoreImage framework

Comment: ok i'm update answer. Hope its help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137098/discussion-between-carpenterblood-and-bimawa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying some more stuff I finally figured it out with the help of Bimawa and this is the changes that I needed to make

```
if self.isEnableBorderDetection == true{
        if self.borderDetectFrames == true {
            let features = self.highAccuracyRectangleDetector().features(in: image)
            self.borderDetectLastRectangleFeature = self.biggestRectangle(rectangles: features)
```

Basically I needed to change the way I was putting the `CIFeatures` into an array to be use by `CIRectangleFeature` functions

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

You use double wrapping in Array:

```
let rectangleFeature: CIRectangleFeature? = self.biggestRectangle(rectangles: [self.highAccuracyRectangleDetector().features(in: enhancedImage!)])
```

Comment: ok after making those changes it runs fine however it doesn't do any rectangle detection because the array is empty because we removed the array on lines 410 and 222

Comment: No on lines 410 and 222, we just remove on more wrapper in array. Problems in `self.highAccuracyRectangleDetector().features(in: image)`  u must reserch why self.highAccuracyRectangleDetector().features(in: image) method return 0 often. Its other a question, I think. Just what the method features must detect?

Comment: features returns an Array of CIFeatures this is right out of the CoreImage framework`/** Returns an array of CIFeature instances in the given image.
     The array is sorted by confidence, highest confidence first. */
    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func features(in image: CIImage) -> [CIFeature]`

Comment: Yes its return array but empty,  `let rects:[CIFeature] = self.highAccuracyRectangleDetector().features(in: enhancedImage!)
                    NSLog("%@", rects)`

Comment: I'm want to skype with u, you have more problems in code. bimawa - Skype acc

Comment: I don't have Skype however I figured it out finally though see updated project in google drive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137101/discussion-between-carpenterblood-and-bimawa).